# Envío de información a traves de IP de datos

Tags: android, android-studio, ip

Buenas tardes,
Estoy realizando una aplicación que envía información a través de la IP de cada uno de los terminales. De esta manera los dos moviles conocen la IP del otro y se comunican. Cuando hago este intercambio de información con los dos terminales conectados al WIFI de mi casa, lo hace todo correctamente.

El problema viene cuando uno de ellos esta conectado a los datos de la compañia. En ese momento aunque el otro terminal conozca su IP no le llega información.
No consigo solucionar este problema, alguien sabría que es lo que puede estar ocurriendo?

Utilizo este código para obtener la IP del terminal:

```
public static String getIP() {
    List<InetAddress> addrs;
    String address = "";
    try {
        List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
        for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
            addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
            for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress() && addr instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    address = addr.getHostAddress().toUpperCase(new Locale("es", "MX"));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Ex getting IP value " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return address;
}
```

Quizás este cogiendo mal la IP de datos del móvil?? O no se puede hacer intercambio de información a traves de las IP de la red de datos??

Gracias a todos y Saludos!!!

Comment: Hola javier una pregunta? siempre el envio de la informacion sera dentro de una misma red, osea los dispositivos siempre estaran conectados al mismo wifi?
que tal una solucion usando sockets? claro que esto te ocacionaria crear una aplicacion destinada a recibir y enviar las solicitudes dependiendo cual sea el caso.

Comment: Javier ¿te has planteado usar [`Firebase`](https://firebase.google.com/?hl=es-419) para esto?

Comment: Hola!! Si me lo he planteado :( pero es un PFG y mi tutor no quiere que se usen servidores externo o la nube. Gracias

Comment: Hola!! No, los usuarios se podrían conectar a otras redes wifi o con su movil a su conexión de datos. Utilizo los sockets y funciona bien cuando están en la misma red wifi, pero cuando desactivo el wifi y activo los datos ya no se intercambian información.

Comment: public void run() {
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());
String ip = usuario.getIp();
Socket sk;
 try {
 sk = new Socket(ip, puerto);
OutputStream salida;
 try { salida = sk.getOutputStream();
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(salida);
 printStream.print(mensaje);
printStream.close();
try {
salida.close();
sk.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println(e);
        } }